# Git rebase -i complains about rebasing without telling which branch, but the resolution is already in the config file

Tags: git

I am trying to do a git rebase -i on my repo. The repo was cloned from github and has only one branch: master. When I issue the rebase -i, git complains that

```
You asked me to rebase without telling me which branch you
want to rebase against, and 'branch.master.merge' in
your configuration file does not tell me, either. Please
specify which branch you want to use on the command line and
try again (e.g. 'git rebase <upstream branch>').
See git-rebase(1) for details.

If you often rebase against the same branch, you may want to
use something like the following in your configuration file:
    [branch "master"]
    remote = <nickname>
    merge = <remote-ref>
    rebase = true

    [remote "<nickname>"]
    url = <url>
    fetch = <refspec>
```

Sure enough, I check in the .git/config, but it already contains what it is suggested

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0 
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge  = master
    rebase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = <url of the repo>
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

At work I routinely perform rebase -i without further specifications, but here at home I need to do rebase -i origin/master for it to work, and I don't understand why.

Git version is 1.7.9.5

*Edit*: Added information as requested

```
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name '@{upstream}'
error: No upstream branch found for ''
@{upstream}
error: No upstream branch found for ''
fatal: ambiguous argument '@{upstream}': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
```

Comment: Are you currently on the master branch? What does `git branch` return?

Comment: @VonC I am on master, which is also the only branch I have both in the local and remote repos.

Comment: Have you fetched origin?

Comment: @tbekolay: I normally pull, but I am the only developer so I am always  synchronized against the remote.

Comment: That's weird and interesting.  What does `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name '@{upstream}'` produce?

Comment: @torek: Added information to the question

Comment: @torek: I try to install git 2.0.1. maybe it's a bug

Comment: It does look like a bug of sorts.  I just also noticed that the `merge =` line should have read `merge = refs/heads/master`, not just `merge = master`; but git should have resolved this differently (as 2.0.1 did).

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Maybe it's a bug.

I updated to git 2.0.1, and now a rebase -i says

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to rebase against.
See git-rebase(1) for details

    git rebase <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master
```

Which is equally strange, as I daily pushed and pulled from the repo, and I successfully pulled also with 2.0.1. In any case, I set the upstream

```
 $ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
```

and now `git rebase -i` works. Mystery.